# Length of path between nodes, allowing for multiple relation types (SPARQL)

Tags: sparql

I have to write a SPARQL query that returns the length of the path between two nodes (:persA and :persD) that are connected by these relationships:

```
@prefix : <http://www.example.org/> .

:persA :knows :knowRelation1 .
:knowRelation1 :hasPerson :persB .
:persB :knows :knowRelation2 .
:knowRelation2 :hasPerson :persC .
:persC :knows :knowRelation3 .
:knowRelation3 :hasPerson :persD .
```

I tried with this query:

```
PREFIX : <http://www.example.org/>

SELECT (COUNT(?mid) AS ?length)
WHERE 
{
    :persA (:knows | :hasPerson)* ?mid .
    ?mid (:knows | :hasPerson)+ :persD .
}
```

the result seems to be a infinite loop.

Any advice/examples of how this can be done?

Comment: 1) what triplestore or SPARQL interface are you using? 2) what error message makes you think that you're stuck in an infinite loop?

Comment: Check @AKSW's comment on my answer.  I saw your message about thousands of relations between hundreds of persons.  How many **unique** relations are there?  Are they always **arranged in a particular order**, like (:knows/:hasPerson)* in your question?

Answer (score 1):

After fixing some syntax errors in your initial post, the provided triples and query work for me in GraphDB Free 8.2 and BlazeGraph 2.1.1.  I have since applied these edits to your post itself.

- added a trailing `/` to your definition of the empty prefix
- added a trailing `.` to your prefix definition line (required if you want to start with a `@`)
- fixed the spelling of length (OK, that's just a cosmetic fix)

.

```
@prefix : <http://www.example.org/> .

:persA :knows :knowRelation1 .
:knowRelation1 :hasPerson :persB .
:persB :knows :knowRelation2 .
:knowRelation2 :hasPerson :persC .
:persC :knows :knowRelation3 .
:knowRelation3 :hasPerson :persD .
```

.

```
PREFIX  :     <http://www.example.org/>

SELECT  (COUNT(?mid) AS ?length)
WHERE
  { :persA (:knows|:hasPerson)* ?mid .
    ?mid (:knows|:hasPerson)+ :persD
  }
```

result:

```
    length
"6"^^xsd:integer
```

[image]

Comment: I apologies for grammatical and syntax mistakes. 

I tried the suggested query but the result is an infinite computation. 

I think that there are loops betweens the nodes in the path. I have to find a way to avoid them. 

The dataset given in the question is just for example, my current dataset has 266 persons and over 1000 knows relations.

Thank you

Comment: @MarkMiller Shouldn't it be the sequence operator `/` in the property path instead of the disjunction operator `|`? This would make more sense to me, at least semantically. In the end, the idea should be to traverse the persons only. Indeed, this wouldn't return the "real" length of the path but it would return the number of person hops. Cheers

Comment: @AKSW I think the key point here is that the triples provided in the question may not give an accurate picture of the "real" triples.  At this point, I would assume that there's no guarantee about the order of predicates.  But let's ask!  I'm adding a comment to the question.

Comment: @M.Polonioli Which triple store do you use? Note, a triple store isn't really optimized for graph traversal queries - there exist probably better-suited graph databases.

Comment: I'm using Apache Rya (https://rya.apache.org/). 

The real triples are a lot but follows the rule specified in the question.

A node that represent a person (:persX) is connected via the :knows relation to a node that represent a know relation (:knowRelationX) 
and a know relation is connected via the :hasPerson relation to another node that represent a person (:persY); 
which is a friend of the start person.

Comment: It's not the loops the problem. I tried to add the simple dataset to my triple store and the query works fine. At this point I think that the problem is that with a very complex dataset the query takes to long. Thank you all.